# Next and previous item in an object with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object "data" as defined:

```
MYLIST
    61:
        ALREADY_EXIST: 1
        ARCHIVE: 0
        CODE_UNIT: "F.5"
        GROUP_TYPE: "Group"
        ID: 61
        SG_CODE: "ABCD00"
    62:
        ALREADY_EXIST: 0
        ARCHIVE: 0
        CODE_UNIT: "D.1"
        GROUP_TYPE: "Sub-Group"
        ID: 62
        SG_CODE: "ABCD11"
    86:
        ALREADY_EXIST: 1
        ARCHIVE: 0
        CODE_UNIT: "B.1"
        GROUP_TYPE: "Group"
        ID: 61
        SG_CODE: "ABC235"
    99:
        ALREADY_EXIST: 0
        ARCHIVE: 0
        CODE_UNIT: "A.2"
        GROUP_TYPE: "Group"
        ID: 62
        SG_CODE: "ABCD11"
SUBJECT_CODE_NUMBER: 4
```

I'm trying to parse this object for displaying value following the previous and nex values.

**I would like to retrieve the next and previous element in variables**, how can I do that?

```
$.each(data.MYLIST,function(k,v){       
    alert(v); //OK
    console.log(data.MYLIST[k].SG_CODE); //OK
    console.log(????); // FOR THE NEXT VALUE
    console.log(????); // FOR THE PREVIOUS VALUE                        
});
```

In Mylist k is not a continuous value. k+1 is not compulsory the following value of k. For example you have the item 62 and after the item is 86.

Thus I cannot use:

```
var next = data.EXPERT_GROUP[k+1].SG_CODE  
var previous= data.EXPERT_GROUP[k-1].SG_CODE
```

In this case do you know a way for getting the next value and the previous value?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Seb

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery `$.each` you can access to the index directly with the first parameter of the function.
Assuming your index can't be negative.

```
 

var previous = -1;
$.each(data.MYLIST,function(k,v){
    alert(v); //OK

    if(previous != -1){
      console.log(data.MYLIST[previous].SG_CODE); // FOR THE PREVIOUS VALUE
    }
    console.log(data.MYLIST[k].SG_CODE); //OK
    previous = k;                     
});
```

Should do the trick for the previous one, don't think you can access next value if your index does not increment on a regular basis.

Comment: Check also if the item in the K index is the last element of the list, otherwise you get an error if you get the element at K+1

Comment: In this case K is key value like 61 or 99 and adding 1 will give you wrong value.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not working because in mylist k+1 is not compulsory the following value of k. For example you have the item 62 and after the item is 86

Comment: Just edited the post according to the comments. Actually i don't know if you can get the next value if your index is random.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array does not have defined values at continuous index locations, you may define a method like:

```
function seekNext(a, index) { 
   for(var i = index; i<a.length; i++){
     if(a[i]){ 
       return a[i] }
     }
};
```

You may invoke this method as `seekNext(data.MYLIST, k)`

Same way one may write seekPrev implementation too.
If the index values of the array are continuous, one could have accessed previous and next values by incrementing and de-incrementing the current array loop index value.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit 28/4/17**

I overwrite the `$.each` method.

**code**

```
a= {"a":{"c":"1"},"b":{"c":"2"},"c":{"c":"3"},"d":{"c":"4"},"e":{"c":"7"},"f":{"c":"9"}};

$.each = function (obj, callback) {
  var length, i;
  this.preAndNext = 0,
    this.previous = { "index": null, "data": null },
    this.now = { "index": null, "data": null };
  if (obj.length) {
    length = obj.length;
    for (; i < length; i++) {
      if (callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]) === false) { break; }
    }
  } else {
    //that's your object need it.
    for (i in obj) {
      if (this.preAndNext) {
        if (callback.call(obj[i], this.now.index, this.previous.data, this.now.data, obj[i]) === false) { break; }
      }
      this.previous = (this.now.data) ? this.now : this.previous;
      this.now = { "index": i, "data": obj[i] };
      this.preAndNext = true;
    }
    callback.call(obj[i], i, (this.now.data ? this.previous.data : null), (this.now.data || this.previous.data), null);
  }
  return obj;
}

$.each(a,function(i,pre,now,next){
  //i:index
  //pre:previous object;
  //now:now state object;
  //next: the next object;
  console.log(i,pre,now,next);
});
```

Add your code after you call jquery.If your loop encounter first or last that element was rendered `null`.(i.e the first loop `pre` = `null`)

Hope to help you.

Comment: I tried that before to post my question, but it's not working I obtain an empty object when I do console.log(next) for instance

Comment: oh.. sorry i thought you use linklist.

Comment: @coeurdange57 I modified the code and show me if it works well.